AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Cloudflare Error : upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
the website was working, but it stopped on 22 May and this error has appeared in Elastic Beanstalk logs

I use CloudFlare linked directly with the Elastic Beanstalk environment domain.
app the  is running using Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.14
Django
I try to restart the environment, I don't know exactly why it happens
